# How to get rid of CUDA out of memory without having to restart the machine?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, python, cuda, gpu

Is there a hack in Ubuntu 20.04 to get rid of the following CUDA out of memory error without having to restart the machine?

> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 40.00 MiB (GPU 0;
> 7.80 GiB total capacity; 6.34 GiB already allocated; 32.44 MiB free; 6.54 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

I understand that the following works but then also kills my Jupyter notebook. Is there a way to free up memory in GPU without having to kill the Jupyter notebook?

```
(base) mona@mona:~/research/facial_landmark$ nvidia-smi
Tue Oct  6 20:28:05 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06    Driver Version: 450.51.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8     9W /  N/A |   7883MiB /  7982MiB |      2%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1306      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                255MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1743      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              151MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3273      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3359      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3844      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4222      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4587      C   ...mona/anaconda3/bin/python     7459MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
(base) mona@mona:~/research/facial_landmark$ kill -9  4587
(base) mona@mona:~/research/facial_landmark$ nvidia-smi
Tue Oct  6 20:28:24 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06    Driver Version: 450.51.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8     9W /  N/A |    433MiB /  7982MiB |      4%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1306      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                255MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1743      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              152MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3273      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3359      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3844      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4222      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
(base) mona@mona:~/research/facial_landmark$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use try using **torch.cuda.empty_cache()**, since PyTorch is the one that's occupying the CUDA memory.

Comment: If for example I shut down my Jupyter kernel without first `x.detach.cpu()` then `del x` then `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`, it becomes impossible to free that memorey from a different notebook. So the solution would not work. Astonished to see that in 2021 it's such a pain to delete stuff from cuda memory.